# How to use multiple dns?

Tags: vpn, dns, proxy

When I connect at work the net is going to assign me a dns that is working fine.

After that when I connect to VPN I'm going to receive a different dns. With this one I can reach the server of the vpn owner but I'm not able to go to the internet.

BUT if I switch the dns with the old ones I'm able to surf again (still connected to the vpn, but I cannot surf their server).

Recap:

> DNS1) MyPC -> CompanyProxy -> Internet
>
> DNS2) MyPc -> CompanyProxy -> VPN -> NoInternet (can Ping vpn servers)
>
> DNS1) MyPC -> CompanyProxy -> VPN -> Internet (cannot ping vpn servers)

Weirdest thing: I'm able to do a nslookup from anywhere, but ping is going to fail.

Is possible to use both DNS? Or setup a dns just on the browser?

I'm quite lost..

Comment: Why don't you just change the DNS servers for the VPN connection to use any DNS server you want?  What problem is solved by using more then a primary and secondary DNS server?

Comment: I cannot use any dns server because the VPN ones are used to resolve some specifical addresses. Anyway I've finally resolved! I'm going to post an answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A colleague has finally found a solution (with the help of another one!).

We've just added a custom route for the address that we needed to resolve from the vpn, so something like

```
sudo route add -net 1.2.3.4 11.22.33.44 255.255.255.0
```

where the `1.2.3.4` is the ip that we need to be resolved from the vpn gateway (`11.22.33.44`) and then we changed in the connection pool of weblogic the name of the database with directly the ip.

It seems to work! :D